# show result from left join in one field

Tags: mysql, field, group-concat

I have this problem with getting all the retrieved values from a left join into one field. When I use the group_concat it concatenates all the values into just one record.

What I need is to retrieve all the image file names from the product based on the left join and then concatenate them in to one field in the record.

```
select  
    pd.products_id, 
    pd.products_name, 
    pd.products_description, 
    pd.products_more,
    pd.seo_title,
    pd.seo_description,

    pa.price,
    pa.price_excl,
    pa.price_action,

    pov.products_options_values_name as size, 

    cdc.categories_name as category_name1,  
    cdp.categories_name as category_name2,
    group_concat(images.filename) as files

from products_description as pd

left join(products as p) ON(p.products_id = pd.products_id) 
left join(categories as c) ON(p.parent_id = c.categories_id)
left join(categories_description as cdp) ON(p.parent_id = cdp.categories_id)
left join(categories_description as cdc) ON(c.parent_id = cdc.categories_id)
left join(products_attributes AS pa) ON(pd.products_id = pa.products_id)
left join(products_options_values AS pov) ON(pov.products_options_values_id = pa.options_values_id)
left join(images) ON(p.products_id = images.item_id);
```

With out the group_contact it returns for example 2000 products it returns for instance 3 records that are the same product only different shoe size. The same images need to be added to the same product concatenated.

A few columns of a few records to understand better what I need to retrieve.

```
products_id | products_name | size | files

1             shoe1           35     image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg
1             shoe1           36.5   image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg
1             shoe1           37     image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg
```

Comment: Think you are just missing the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You should have added `group by`, as you indicated correctly in the tags, but not yet in the query. Aggregations like `group_concat` (and similarly `count`, `sum`, `max` and others), generate their outcome per group. Using `group by` you can indicate which groups you have. If you don't specify that, the whole data set will be seen as one group, and you get only one record as a result.

Most databases require the selected fields to be either in the `group by` or be an aggregation themselves, but MySQL doesn't have that requirement, so adding `group_concat` will just make the query return one row with all the images and *any* product and size (more or less randomly).

I'm not sure which fields you need to group, but it seems you need at least *productid* and *size*, which means you query should look like this:

```
select  
  pd.products_id, 
  pd.products_name, 
  pd.products_description, 
  pd.products_more,
  pd.seo_title,
  pd.seo_description,

  pa.price,
  pa.price_excl,
  pa.price_action,

  pov.products_options_values_name as size, 

  cdc.categories_name as category_name1,  
  cdp.categories_name as category_name2,
  group_concat(images.filename) as files

from products_description as pd
left join(products as p) ON(p.products_id = pd.products_id) 
left join(categories as c) ON(p.parent_id = c.categories_id)
left join(categories_description as cdp) ON(p.parent_id = cdp.categories_id)
left join(categories_description as cdc) ON(c.parent_id = cdc.categories_id)
left join(products_attributes AS pa) ON(pd.products_id = pa.products_id)
left join(products_options_values AS pov) ON(pov.products_options_values_id = pa.options_values_id)
left join(images) ON(p.products_id = images.item_id)
group by
  pd.products_id, 
  pov.products_options_values_name
```

Comment: A ok thanks it sounds logical :) Thanks for the tip now it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a group by clause

```
SELECT pd.products_id, 
        pd.products_name, 
        pd.products_description, 
        pd.products_more,
        pd.seo_title,
        pd.seo_description,
        pa.price,
        pa.price_excl,
        pa.price_action,
        pov.products_options_values_name AS size, 
        cdc.categories_name AS category_name1,  
        cdp.categories_name AS category_name2,
        GROUP_CONCAT(images.filename) AS files
FROM products_description AS pd
LEFT OUTER JOIN(products AS p) ON (p.products_id = pd.products_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN(categories AS c) ON (p.parent_id = c.categories_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN(categories_description AS cdp) ON (p.parent_id = cdp.categories_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN(categories_description AS cdc) ON (c.parent_id = cdc.categories_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN(products_attributes AS pa) ON (pd.products_id = pa.products_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN(products_options_values AS pov) ON (pov.products_options_values_id = pa.options_values_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN(images) ON(p.products_id = images.item_id)
GROUP BY pd.products_id, 
        pd.products_name, 
        pd.products_description, 
        pd.products_more,
        pd.seo_title,
        pd.seo_description,
        pa.price,
        pa.price_excl,
        pa.price_action,
        pov.products_options_values_name AS size, 
        cdc.categories_name AS category_name1,  
        cdp.categories_name AS category_name2
```

This will merge all rows there the columns listed in the group by clause are the same. When the merge is done it allows the aggregate function (such as GROUP_CONCAT in this case, but also SUM, AVG, etc) to work on those groups of merged rows.

Note that MySQL does not complain if there is a non aggregate column that is not listed in the GROUP BY clause, but if they do not all have the same value for that group of rows then which value is used is not determined - could be any of them. Most other flavours of SQL will just error in this situation.